# About EC2 Instance Storage volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I create an EC2 instance store, I'm not able to stop the instance through the console. But AWS documentation mentioning that " if you **stop** or terminate an instance, any data on instance store volumes is lost." There is no option available to stop the instance store EC2 instance. Can anyone Explain why AWS talking about the **Stop** operation which is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

From the [AMI Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html) documentation: Instances launched from Instance Store-Backed AMI cannot be stopped -- instances are either running or terminated.  Instances launched from EBS-backed AMIs have a persistent root volume, thus they can be stopped.

The point of confusion is that instances can still *use* instance store volumes (if so designed) even though the instance is launched from an EBS-backed AMI.  In this case, when the instance is stopped, the data on the instance store volumes is lost, but since the root volume (and possibly other volumes, if so configured) is safely persisted in EBS, the instance can be started again with the data on the EBS volumes intact.  Instance store volumes will again be attached, but they will be empty -- all data on those volumes is lost if the instance is stopped.